# Use continuity to evaluate the limit of $e^{x^2-x}$ as $x$ approaches $1$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Use continuity to evaluate the following limit:

Lim as x approaches $1$ of $e^{x^2-x}$

By plugging $1$ in, I get $1$ (should be the correct answer) but I am not sure how I would prove it using continuity.

Comment: Are you thinking about an epsilon-delta proof?

Comment: @SheheryarZaidi no, not an epsilon delta proof but something that says something about the continuity of the function

Answer (score 1):

A function is continuous at $x$ iff its limit at $x$ equals to what you get when you plug in $x$.

By the way, the result is $e^0$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} e^{((x^2)-x)} = 1$

Thus, this is equivalent of saying $\frac {\lim\limits_{x \to 1} e^{x^2}}{\lim\limits_{x \to 1} e^x}$

Then using the continuity of $e^x$ at $x=1$, you can write the $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} e^x$ as $e^{\lim\limits_{x \to 1} x}$

Similarly, you can use the continuity of $e^{x^2}$ at $x=1$, so you can write $ {\lim\limits_{x \to 1} e^{x^2}}$ into $e^{\lim\limits_{x \to 1} x^2}$

Both results in $e$. And so, it should be clear enough that the result is indeed 1.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that since $e^x$ and $x^2-x$ are both continuous functions the composition namely $e^{x^2-x}$ will be continuous. Now think about how continuity relates to limits to get the existence of the limit.